# Magento 2: Form Validator is not a function

Tags: magento2, php, form-validation

I am trying to use the new Magento 2 version and I have discovered that the form validator doesn't work as well.

When I try to add a product in the amdinistration panel I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.validator.validateSingleElement is not a function
```

[image: error]

I have seen the requirejs-config.js and I can see the form validator. So why this happens?

[image: code magento 2]

The error seems to me clear but it's not so clear the solution for me. How have I to solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm now running into the same problem, since I updated to 2.1. Before I also had [this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2843#issuecomment-207952150) which I solved with that same fix. After that I saw the same error you're mentioning and it boiled down to being a local browser cache problem. So to fix it, try emptying your own browser cache. If that doesn't do the trick, first make sure you've deleted the magento cache and rebuild/recompile everything and try again. At least "it works on my machine".

Comment: Can confirm that deleting local cached fixed this issue.